# Converting a Python list for use with rpy2 FloatVector

Tags: python, rpy2

This code works great (in no small part thanks to the SO geniuses that helped me)

```
import os
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import IntVector, FloatVector

with open ('sampleSizeWrapper.R') as fh:
        rcode = os.linesep.join(fh.readlines())
        wrapper = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(rcode,"wrapper")

a=(0.8,0.9,0.95,0.995);

wrapper.saveSpecContours(IntVector((0,1)),
                 0.1, FloatVector(a),
                 0.001, 1, 986)
```

With "a" being hard coded like this..I'm not having an issue but when I pass a value to my Python script (from the web via JSON) that looks like this...

```
a=data["sens"]
```

"a" then becomes "0.8,0.9,0.95,0.995"

but when trying to call FloatVector(a) on this I am getting...

```
ValueError: Error while trying to convert element 1 to a double.
```

My newbie status with Python has me a bit confused on why this won't work (although I'm sure it has to do with converting a Python list to a 1D vector) Does anyone have an idea as to how I could make "a" work with FloatVector when it's not hard coded?

Thank you so much. JW

Comment: `a=data["sens"].split(',')` I believe will do what you want.

Comment: Looks like `a` is a string.  It should be a list of floats.  We can fix that, but your JSON decoding should have handled that already (unless it was improperly encoded in the first place).  How is `data` being constructed?

Comment: Thanks DSM. It is a string. It's merely a comma separated list of values input into a text box on a webpage.

Comment: user2097159: it works like a champ and that's the answer I needed. DSM I upvoted too. Really and truly guys, you have no idea how much this helps. JW